# Memcache Cluster / Replication / Delete Solution?

Tags: php, memcached

I want to create a memcache cluester for my site but I have few doubts:

- whether it stores data on all nodes or replicate data to other nodes?
- How memcache cluester serve the response for the request for a key?
- How can I delete the data from the cluster?

Comment: memcache does __not__ replicate data across all nodes in a cluster, it picks __one__ node within the cluster to store any given key/value pair

Comment: ... and to delete data, you have to iterate over your cluster to remove the key you want. Be careful, memcache node is just a pool not a cluster with replication.